# ERROR: Nuxt error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, nuxt.js

I am trying to run an old project which is running in node - v8.15.0 and nuxt - v1.4.1. when I try to build it is showing like,

> baseURL: http://localhost:3000/api/
> nuxt:axios 19:00:45
>
> browserBaseURL: http://localhost:3000/api/
> nuxt:axios 19:00:45
>
> ERROR  Nuxt error
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>
> index.js:40 ModuleContainer.module.exports
> [BTS-backend]/[@nuxtjs]/auth/lib/module/index.js:40:32
>
> module.js:162 Promise [BTS-backend]/[nuxt]/lib/core/module.js:162:30
>
> new Promise
>
> module.js:146 ModuleContainer.addModule
> [BTS-backend]/[nuxt]/lib/core/module.js:146:12
>
> utils.js:96 promise.then
> [BTS-backend]/[nuxt]/lib/common/utils.js:96:43
>
> next_tick.js:189 process._tickCallback
> internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7
>
> module.js:696 Function.Module.runMain module.js:696:11
>
> bootstrap_node.js:204 startup bootstrap_node.js:204:16
>
> bootstrap_node.js:625  bootstrap_node.js:625:3
>
> nuxt:build App root: G:\Project\BTS\BTS-backend\nuxt +0ms nuxt:build
> Generating G:\Project\BTS\BTS-backend.nuxt files... +1ms nuxt:build
> Generating files... +15ms nuxt:build Generating routes... +12ms
> nuxt:build Building files... +318ms nuxt:build Adding webpack
> middleware... +901ms 25% building modules{ parser: "babylon" } is
> deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }. 55% building
> modulesNode#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append. 100%
>
> Build completed in 144.496s
>
> DONE  Compiled successfully in 133500ms
> OPEN  http://localhost:3000

Here build is getting completed but I cannot access any routes it showing "Cannot GET /"

Packeage.json

```
{   "name": "server",   "version": "0.0.0",   "private": true,   "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000",
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "heroku-postbuild": "nuxt build",
    "db:seed": "./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all",
    "db:migrate": "./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate",
    "nuxt:build": "nuxt build",
    "nuxt:start": "node ./bin/www && nuxt start"   },   "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.5.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.1",
    "@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.0.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
    "await-to-js": "^2.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "bcrypt-promise": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "nuxt": "^1.4.1",
    "parse-error": "^0.2.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.38",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "redirect-ssl": "^1.3.0",
    "s": "^0.1.1",
    "sequelize": "^4.38.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^0.6.4",
    "validator": "^9.2.0",
    "vue-ckeditor5": "^0.4.1",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^2.4.4",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^2.4.1",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.3"   },   "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "^2.0.1",
    "cropperjs": "^1.4.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "glob-all": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "pagination": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^5.1.0",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.2",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^0.23.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "vue-good-table": "^2.14.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-paginatron": "^0.1.5",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-upload-component": "^2.8.11",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"   },   "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"   } }
```

I am actually new to nuxtjs. please anyone help.

Comment: The issue is resolved

Comment: how you resolved this issue?

Comment: It was an issue with the installed node_modules. I deleted the existing folder and run the npm i command after changing the node version to 8.15, previously I have installed some of the packages with the version 12.14.0. It was the issue for me

Comment: thank you, it brings my project able to run again